# How To Use One Data Class For Two View Pager Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

In my app, there is a viewpager fragment that contains 2 tab. First tab is all data, second tab is top 10 data.

When the fragment is loaded, it calls two API Endpoints

```
@GET("api/get-all")
suspend fun getAllLinks(@Query("userid") userID: String, @Query("token") token: String, @Query("page") page: Int) : Respond

@GET("api/topten")
suspend fun getTopTen(@Query("userid") userid: String, @Query("token")token: String): Respond
```

Both of them will return the data to Respond data class

```
data class Respond(
val error: List<ErrorMsg>?,
val data: List<DataContent>?,
val token: String?,
)
```

The problem is, when I want to show the data to the recylerview, only the data of All Data that is shown

I'm guessing it's because there is only one instance of Respond data class that only holds data of All Data.

Because when I create another data class named RespondTop

```
data class RespondTop(
val error: List<ErrorMsgTop>?,
val data: List<DataContentTop>?,
val token: String?,
)
```

and change

```
@GET("api/topten")
suspend fun getTopTen(@Query("userid") userid: String, @Query("token")token: String): Respond
```

to this

```
@GET("api/topten")
suspend fun getTopTen(@Query("userid") userid: String, @Query("token")token: String): RespondTop
```

Both All Data and Top Data are shown

So, my question is, how do I return both all data and top data into one data class without needing to create another data class?

Update

Here is the AllDataViewModel

```
fun getData(userid: String, token: String, page: Int){
    val job = viewModelScope.launch {
        _loading.value = true
        try {
            val getData = Network.networkService.getAll(userid, token, page)
            _respond.value = getData
            _loading.value = false
            _error.value = false
            _isCancelled.value = false
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("AllLinksException", e.message.toString())
            _loading.value = false
            if(e.message.toString() == "StandaloneCoroutine was cancelled"){
                _error.value = false
                _isCancelled.value = true
            } else {
                _error.value = true
                _isCancelled.value = false
            }
        }
    }
    resetValue()

    runningJob = job
}
```

This is I observe the data in AllLink Fragment

```
viewModel.respond.observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
        it?.let {
            binding.shimmer.visibility = View.GONE
            binding.rvLinks.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            Utils.sharedPreferenceString(sharedPreferences, "token", it.token.toString())
            token = it.token.toString()
            if (it.error?.get(0)?.invalidToken != null) {
                Utils.showToast(requireContext(), it.error.get(0).invalidToken.toString())
            } else {
                    for (i in 0..it?.data!!.size - 1) {
                        links.add(
                            CurrentLink(
                                it.data.get(i).ID.toString(),
                                it.data.get(i).title.toString(),
                                it.data.get(i).createdDate.toString()
                            )
                        )
                    }
                    totalLink = it.data.get(0).totalLink!!.toInt()
                    binding.tvTotalLinks.text = totalLink.toString()
                    linkAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                }
                page++
            }
        }
```

TopData ViewModel

```
fun getData(userid: String, token: String){
    viewModelScope.launch {
        try {
            val data = Network.networkService.getTopTen(userid, token)
            _respond.value = data
        }catch (e: Exception){
            Log.e("Top Ten Exception", e.message.toString())
        }
    }
}
```

This is TopTenFragment

```
binding = FragmentTopBinding.inflate(inflater)
    viewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(TopDataViewModel::class.java)
    sharedPreferences = requireActivity().getSharedPreferences(SHARED_PREF_KEY, Context.MODE_PRIVATE)
    val userid = sharedPreferences.getString("userid", null)
    val token = sharedPreferences.getString("token", null)
    viewModel.getData(userid.toString(), token.toString())
    val adapter = TopTenAdapter()
    binding.rvLinks.adapter = adapter

    viewModel.respond.observe(viewLifecycleOwner){
        Log.i("Data Link", "jkfdjksf")
        Log.i("Data Link Top", it.toString())
        binding.shimmer.visibility = View.GONE
        binding.rvLinks.visibility = View.VISIBLE

        if(it?.error!!.get(0).invalidToken != null){
            Utils.showToast(requireContext(), it.error.get(0).invalidToken.toString())
        } else {
            Log.i("Data Link Top", it.toString())
        }
    }
    return binding.root
```

Comment: Can you post your code on how you observe the data from the api response and how you post your data into your `RecyclerView`'s?

Comment: I've edited the post. Hopefully it's clearer now

Comment: how is the `viewModel.respond` populated? you post the request results somewhere in the ViewModel? if you `_respond` is the related MutableLiveData then you can use `_respond.postValue(data)` this should notify the observer